# Transformation of an $L^1$ function by a homomorphism of measure space is also an $L^1$ function.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{D},\nu)$ be two complete measure spaces and $\alpha:\mathscr{D}\rightarrow \mathscr{B}$ be a homomorphism, i.e., a map satisfying

1. $\alpha(A_1\cup A_2)=\alpha(A_1)\cup \alpha(A_2)$ for all $A_1,A_2\in\mathscr{D}$,
2. $\alpha(A^c)=\alpha(A)^c$ for all $A\in\mathscr{D}$,
3. $\mu(\alpha(A))=\nu(A)$ for all $A\in\mathscr{D}$.

**Question:** Show that if $f\in L^1(Y,\mathscr{D},\nu)$ and $g : X \to \mathbb R$ satisfy $\alpha(f^{-1}B)=g^{-1}(B)$ for all measurable $B \subseteq \mathbb R$, then $g\in L^1(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ and $\left\lVert f\right\rVert_1=\left\lVert g\right\rVert_1$.

If $\alpha=T^{-1}$ for some measure-preserving map $T:X\rightarrow Y$, then the answer of the above question follows from the change of variable formula for integration. But how to proceed for a general homomorphism? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hint: first prove that $\int f d\nu=\int g d\mu$ fro simple functions.

Comment: But how do you extend that for arbitrary $L^1$ function?

Comment: @Surajit The simple functions form a dense linear subspace, right?

Comment: Is the map $f\mapsto g$ is continuous  on $L^1$ with respect to the condition $\alpha(f^{-1}(B))=g^{-1}(B)$ for all $B$? More explicitly, if for all $B$, $\alpha(f^{-1}(B))=g^{-1}(B)$ holds for some $f\in L^1(Y,\mathscr{D},\nu)$, and if a sequence of simple functions $\{f_n\}_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ norm, then can we show $\{g_n\}_n$ converges to $g$ in $L^1$ norm, where $g_n$ is the function satisfying $\alpha(f_n^{-1}(B))=g_n^{-1}(B)$ for each $B$ and $n$?

Comment: @Surajit can you show how you do it for the case $\alpha = T^{-1}$?

Comment: @mathworker21 If $T^{-1}f^{-1}(B)=g^{-1}(B)$ for all measurable $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then $g=f\circ T$. Now $T$ is measure preserving implies $\left\lVert f\circ T\right\rVert_1=\left\lVert f\right\rVert_1$. The last statement is called 'The Change of variable formula' for integration. It is proved first for simple $L^1$ functions, then for positive $L^1$ functions using Monotone convergence theorem, then for arbitrary function. But to mimic the argument of the proof of this 'Change of variable formula' for  positive $L^1$ functions, I got stuck as mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lambda \ge 0$, let $B_\lambda = (-\infty,-\lambda] \cup [\lambda,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then, $$||g||_1 = \int_0^\infty \mu(g^{-1} B_\lambda)d_\lambda = \int_0^\infty \mu(\alpha(f^{-1}B_\lambda))d\lambda = \int_0^\infty \nu(f^{-1}B_\lambda)d\lambda = ||f||_1.$$